# Why nuclear tests move under ground since 1964?

Tags: nuclear-physics, history, nuclear-engineering, atomic-physics

According to this database:

http://www.ga.gov.au/oracle/nuclear-explosion.jsp

Since 1962, 99% of USA Nuclear tests was underground.

Since 1964, 99% of Soviet Nuclear tests was underground.

Is it ecologies nuance, or what?

Comment: Downvoted due to insufficient own research. A quick look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuclear_weapons_testing would give you the reasons.

Comment: Even without looking at wikipedia, the answer is pretty obvious. "Ecologies nuance" is a nice name for it. There is nothing very subtle about it.

Comment: I am not sure, how much this is really a physics question. It could be about biology, politics, etc too ...

Answer (score 5):

Three countries signed a treaty banning all nuclear tests but underground ones in 1963 (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_Nuclear_Test_Ban_Treaty ), partly for ecological reasons.

EDIT (08/3/2013): The official reasons are given in the preamble of the treaty (http://www.state.gov/t/isn/4797.htm ):

"The Governments of the United States of America, the United Kingdom of Great Britain and Northern Ireland, and the Union of Soviet Socialist Republics, hereinafter referred to as the "Original Parties,"

Proclaiming as their principal aim the speediest possible achievement of an agreement on general and complete disarmament under strict international control in accordance with the objectives of the United Nations which would put an end to the armaments race and eliminate the incentive to the production and testing of all kinds of weapons, including nuclear weapons,

Seeking to achieve the discontinuance of all test explosions of nuclear weapons for all time, determined to continue negotiations to this end, and desiring to put an end to the contamination of mans environment by radioactive substances,

Have agreed as follows:"

Comment: if you count as ecological the long term effects of radiation on humans.

Comment: @ anna v:There are the following words in the preamble of the treaty: "desiring to put an end to the contamination of mans environment by radioactive substances" (http://www.state.gov/t/isn/4797.htm ) - this is clearly an "ecological" reason, in my book. And I would think this is not necessarily about "long-term" effects: sometimes nuclear tests had caused acute radiation sickness (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daigo_Fukury%C5%AB_Maru )

Comment: It also provides less information to the opposition. It's harder for spy sats to measure the yield and harder to collect any samples of the waste products to identify the weapon design or performance.